# Push comments from JIRA to Salesforce using APIs

Tags: salesforce, jira, jira-rest-api, salesforce-communities, jira-rest-java-api

My Project is looking for a way to push the comments from JIRA to Salesforce without using a plugin/third party tools due to bureaucratic overhead. I have searched a lot and every one of them suggests a plugin.

Is this possible ? Any examples of a solution without using a plugin will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible, but a pre-built commercial solution will more cost efficient to install and maintain in the long term compared to building a one-off custom solution privately.

As for asking for an *"example of a solution"*, that's like asking for an *"example of how to build a space ship from stuff"* because there are just so many different ways to solve that problem using so many different languages, toolsets, frameworks and methods. If you're using Jira Cloud and you know Java, then I advise your easiest path is Atlassian's Forge framework.

Have fun.